# Setting input parameter types in SQLAlchemy raw SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to execute some raw SQL and take advantage of SQLAlchemy's SQL injection prevention.

My code is similar to this bit:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

DB_URI = '...'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(DB_URI)

sql = text("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE userid = :userid")
res = engine.execute(sql, userid=12345)
# do something with the result...
```

The problem is that `userid` in `some_table` is of type `varchar`. All I want to do is to tell SQLAlchemy to convert `12345` to a string before executing the statement. I know how I could do the conversion both in Python and in SQL. But I remember that I once used a explicit type definition in SQLAlchemy, I just can't find it anymore. Can someone point me to the right direction?
(My actual question involves postgresql arrays of BIGINTs vs. INTs, but I tried to keep it simple.)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a bit old already, but knowing myself, I will probably come back for this in future.
This was the bit of code I was looking for:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam
from sqlalchemy.types import String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

DB_URI = '...'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(DB_URI)

sql = text("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE userid = :userid").bindparams(bindparam("userid", String))
res = engine.execute(sql, userid=12345)

# in particular this bit is useful when you have a list of ids
sql = text("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE userids = :userids").bindparams(bindparam("userids", ARRAY(String)))
res = engine.execute(sql, userids=[12345, 12346, 12347])
```

Answer (score -3):

From what I see, there are two kind of "duh" ways to do it if I am not missing anything -

**1st Way**
WARNING THIS IS SUSCEPTIBLE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACKS, DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION

```
userid=12345 # defining here
sql = text("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE userid = '"+userid+"'")
res = engine.execute(sql)
```

**2nd Way**

```
sql = text("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE userid = :userid")
res = engine.execute(sql, userid=str(12345))
```

Comment: Yeah - I knew both of these... (There is also the way of explicitly type casting in SQL). But my issue is that I have an postgresql array of integers that I want to compare against an array of BIGINTs. I know there are types in sqlalchemy and I seem to remember that there is a way of explicitly setting a type for a text() command. (btw. 1st way is a bad idea because of `userid="';DROP TABLE some_table; --"`)

Comment: can you please edit the question to include these details? Its very hard to narrow down a solution and we will only end up guessing stuff

Comment: The first answer appears to lead to SQL Injection. Such answers should be removed to prevent inexperienced users from copy pasting vulnerable code into production and reduce the amount of bad code here.